# Python - Is there any way to get pip without setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, pip, easy-install

Seems kinda weird that they'd require a package manager to install a package manager.  I'm on Windows BTW.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/95592

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pip does require setuptools. Pip is really just a wrapper around setuptools to provide a better installer than easy_install and some nicer installation behaviors, plus uninstall, requirements files, etc. Even if you somehow got pip installed without setuptools it still won't run without it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Distribute` instead of `setuptools`: it installs a package called `setuptools` (it's a fork of the latter). You can install Distribute by downloading and running [`distribute_setup.py`](http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py).

**Update:** As Gringo Suave says, the above is obsolete now - `distribute` and `setuptools` have now merged, and the merged project is called `setuptools`.

Comment: Obsolete since Aug 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You can download `setuptools` package as Windows installer from [pypi/setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and then install `pip` or `easy_install`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Windows Users

If you installed [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) on Windows, then you have pip by default, as well as PyPM (ActiveState's package manager). The following excerpt is from [What's included in ActivePython 2.7](https://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/404):

> **Additional Packages**
>
> - **PyPM**: Python Package Manager to download and install binary packages. Also included: virtualenv, Distribute, pip, SQLAlchemy.

### Solution for OS X Users

Not sure if `setuptools` is required when installing [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). You might try that.

To install homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/raw/323731/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Then to install pip:

```
brew install pip
```

Comment: Update: Homebrew no longer ships a `pip` formula. The recommended way to get it is via `easy_install pip`. The OS X System python includes Setuptools and the Homebrew Python packages include Distribute, so `easy_install` should always be available.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just grab the source from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/0.8.2#downloads

unpack it, cd into it, and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: I tried that but it won't work because setup.py contains this lovely line of code: from setuptools import setup